# Does XText have an override operation to recover only part of the right hand side of a rule without the need to name it

Tags: xtext

In grako one can use the `@:e` to invoke an override operator, thatmake the AST for the complete rule be the AST for e. If more than one item is added, the entry is converted to a list. The override operator is useful to recover only part of the right hand side of a rule without the need to name it, and then add a semantic action to recover the interesting part.

Does Xtext has anything like this? I know that += will result in a list, but I cannot find a way to not do something like `X+=stuff`, where X is a name of the lhs

For example, how would one translate this to xtext

```
X1 =@:x{',' @:x}* ';'
```

My original though was

```
X1:  <not sure> +=x (',' <not sure>+=x)* ';' ;
```

____EDIT ______
The idea is that for ever named list in the statements, i.e., nameList1 list1, nameList2 list2, nameList3 list3

I can invoke the stmt_list rule, that will put elements into the correct list
    'statements'
        ( 'nameList1' list1+=stmt_list
        | 'nameList2' list2+=stmt_list)*
        'nameList3' list3+:stmt_list

```
stmt_list:
    stmt_list+=stmt_def (',' stmt_list+=stmt_def )* ';';
```

So here stmt_list+= should match the right list that invoked it.

Thus, when i'll be writing my language after the rules were parsed
I will be able to write something like this

```
  nameList1 foo(a, b, c, d)
  nameList1  bar(e);
  nameList2  zap();
  nameList3 zip();
```

where a,b,c,d,e will go into the right named list

So basically, it should something like this, but instead of rewriting the all list structure every time in every type of named list, I have a shared rule

```
( 'nameList1' list1+=stmt_def (',' list1+=stmt_def )* ';';
| 'nameList2' list2+=stmt_def (',' list2+=stmt_def )* ';';
 'nameList3' list3+=stmt_def (',' list3+=stmt_def )* ';';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if i understand you but you can use so called assigned actions for a kind of AST rewrite.

this is ususally used to write expressions https://typefox.io/parsing-expressions-with-xtext

you could do something like the following but i dont know if this is what you want to do

```
Model:
    (things+=Thing ";")*
;

Thing:
    SimpleThing (({ThingList.things+=current}"," things+=SimpleThing) ("," things+=SimpleThing)* )?
;

SimpleThing:
    name=ID
;
```

Comment: added an edit to my question to better explain.
I do have two questions about your current answer
where do you define things.
is it that things can contain either a thing or a simple thing, and a thing can also contain a simple thing?
why things.list has .things?

Comment: i still do not understand what your requirements are. can you explain by a model and the ast you want to have created. in my case a thing can be either a simplething or a thinglist which is a  list of simple things. (ich you write the comma it is automatically turned into a list. and the left handside (aka ```current```is assigned as a member to that list). since in xtext there is no such thing like everything is a list or a dict (using terms from grako doc) but everything is a dict with the possibility of the (typed) values can be a list i have to introduce ThingList as explicit named type

Comment: but where did you define ThingList?

Also, I'll try to explain again I have 'statments' , which is a key word under it can be several lists of list for example
type1 has a list of stmt1. each of these list has a list stmt_list, 
in stmt_list I am trying to put X into that stmt_list

Comment: Thinglist is created.

Comment: If you simply want to add Stuff to a list use list+=Stuff ("," list+=Stuff)*

Comment: And this way it is not possible to mix the lists if that is what you want. Therefore you would have move the list the the main rule what you already have 'type1' listEkememts+=ListEkement

Comment: I guess I did a poor job explaining myself.
the Idea hear that I have several lists with different names 
'type1' stmt1+=stmt_list, for example the list stmt1 with the name 'type1', and I would like to add elements to that list, elements separated by a , and end with ;

since, I have several different lists with several different names, but all should support the same structure of , and ;.

The idea of stmt_list is to be that generic rule, that will just know to add element to the named list to invoked the rule. 

so @ kind of points to the last named list that invoked that rule.

Comment: Edited the question again

Comment: generic lists / templates are not possible